# interchangeable shebang line in Python script for dual OSes?

Tags: python, shebang

A script is developed both on OS X and Windows using a virtualenv. The so-called developer has already installed all required packages using a `requirements.txt` file, but one problem remains:

If the script is running on OS X, the beginning of each Python file must start like this:

```
#!/Users/os-x-username/.virtualenvs/some_env/bin/python
#!C:\Users\windows-username\Envs\some_env\Scripts\python.exe
```

But if developing on Windows, the line order must be switched:

```
#!C:\Users\windows-username\Envs\some_env\Scripts\python.exe
#!/Users/os-x-username/.virtualenvs/some_env/bin/python
```

How can the so-called developer avoid this tediousness?

Comment: Windows does not recognize the shebang as there is no `+x` file mode on any Windows sanctioned FS. From Windows' perspective it might as well say `#!Bob's your uncle`.

Comment: @zwer: Well from my (admittedly very little) experience (can I can probably find a stackoverflow reference as well), you are wrong. Omitting the windows shebang line from my script and attempting to run it on Windows results in a complaint of libraries not being found, or a python not found in path. If I do put the line back, the scripts run fine.

Comment: How are you running it on Windows? Are you using a Unix emulator like Cygwin?

Comment: Windows doesn't care, but Python launcher does. Those are two very different things ;)

Comment: @zwer: thanks for clarifying. Any solutions to the Python launcher part? (I'm using an atom (the editor) package to run those scripts)

Comment: @zerohedge - if you want to define specific interpreters within virtualenvs, then I'm afraid you're out of luck - unless you want to write your own Python launcher. Would you consider wrapping your script into a launcher script?

Comment: @zwer - I'm not even sure what this means. Got any useful links?

Comment: @zerohedge - what I mean is would it be ok with you to use an additional script just to run your script in the correct environment? Think of it as a launcher/bootstrap script where you'll define you virtualenvs (or use external config, or environment variables or...) and then launch that script instead. Then the script would run your real script based on the virtualenv paths defined and the OS it currently runs on.

Comment: @zwer - I think so, yes. But I can't say for sure because I'm not sure what that would entail..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind adding extra steps, ou can create a launcher script `launcher.py` like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import sys

if __name__ != "__main__":
    print("This is a launcher. Please run only as a main script.")
    exit(-1)

INTERPRETERS = {
    "win": r"C:\Users\windows-username\Envs\some_env\Scripts\python.exe",  # Windows
    "darwin": "/Users/os-x-username/.virtualenvs/some_env/bin/python",  # OSX
    "linux": "/home/linux-user/.virtualenvs/some_env/bin/python"  # Linux
    # etc.
}

TARGET_SCRIPT = "original_script_name.py"

interpreter = None
for i in INTERPRETERS:  # let's find a suitable interpreter for the current platform
    if sys.platform.startswith(i):
        interpreter = i
        break
if not interpreter:
    print("No suitable interpreter found for platform:", sys.platform)
    exit(-1)

main_proc = subprocess.Popen([interpreter, TARGET_SCRIPT] + sys.argv[1:])  # call virtualenv
main_proc.communicate()  # wait for it to finish

exit(main_proc.poll())  # redirect the return code
```

Since this script is there only to run the `original_script_name.py` in the desired interpreter for the current platform, it doesn't matter what its shebang is - as long as it picks any Python interpreter it will be fine.

It would act as a drop-in replacement for your original script (`original_script_name.py`) so just call `launcher.py` instead and it will even redirect the CLI arguments if needed.

Comment: The only thing I don't understand about your answer is the first sentence. I don't really see any extra steps really! It's just run this py file instead of that py file. A big thank you!